# OSX 10.10. Yosemite Clang & GCC Versions

Tags: macos, gcc, clang, osx-yosemite

Trying to diagnose a work development laptop... What version of Clang and GCC come standard with OSX 10.10 Yosemite?

This is what I have on my Mavericks... machine, will respond with my home iMac when it boots.

```
which clang
/usr/bin/clang

which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

clang --version
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.27) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix

gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 4):

On my Mac OS X 10.10.1 with the current XCode (6.1.1 (6A2008a)), I get:

```
$ /usr/bin/clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
$ /usr/bin/gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
$
```

In other words, 'GCC' is no longer the real GNU `gcc` but is `clang`.

Comment: Thanks! Having lots off issue on this machine, it's reporting back GCC as 4.2 even though xcode 6.1.1 is installed.

Trying it all over again.

Comment: Make sure you run the XCode UI; I think you'll find it installs the command line tools.  If not, you have to go get them from Apple's developer site - Command Line Tools.  I've downloaded both ways sufficiently often I've forgotten which is the current one.

Comment: I have tried running the UI and that did not help.

I am downloading the latest xCode build and CLI Tools from Apple now, we'll see how that pans out.

Thanks!

Comment: If you installed gcc separately or otherwise had it leftover from the earlier install it will, of course, replace the gcc stub that points to clang that comes with the dev tools by default. May want to do a `which gcc` to see where you gcc is coming from.

Comment: @jshier, I did a which gcc, it points to /usr/bin/gcc. If I rename the file there is nothing to replace it.

Not sure what the next step is really.

Answer (score 4):

Try running: `xcode-select --install`, followed by: `xcodebuild -license`

Answer (score 0):

After many failed attempts at updating the C Compilers, we did a fresh install of Yosemite and it was fixed.

Not a great solution, but without trying to hand build Clang the sane as Mac native it was the only solution.